# why do all the files in app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Entity contain empty classes (Magento v 1.7)? Were they relocated

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to create custom fields for customer registration in Magento v 1.7 by following the well-used blog post [by fontis](http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/know-more-about-your-customers-adding-custom-signup-attributes). However the post was created for Magento v 1.3 and it seems that the above file has been since relocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they were relocated, sort of. Since Magento 1.7 the `..._Entity_...` and `..._Mysql4_...` classes were renamed to `..._Resource_...`. The old classes are still present for backwards compatibility but inherit from the new ones. So just look which class `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_...` extends. Regardless, between 1.3 and 1.7 were more major changes in the customer model, so you should better find a newer tutorial.